# how to print Horizontaly My project members avatar in laravel blade file?

Tags: php, css, html, laravel-5

I have some member avatar printing in my Laravel blade file.

```
@foreach( $project->collaborators as $collaborator)
    <div>
        <span>
            <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
            {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->name}}
        </span>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

this is printing vertically in My blade file. But I need print this horizontally. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the div display method to inline, instead of the default block:

```
 @foreach( $project->collaborators as $collaborator)
     <div class="collaborator">
         <span>
             <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
                             {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->name}}
         </span>
      </div>
 @endforeach
```

And in the css:

```
.collaborator {
    display: inline;
    /*width: 200px; probably you'll need to set the width*/
}
```